# How to exclude non-unit tests from runs across multiple installations of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, testing, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I am aware of multiple methods one can use to keep certain types of test out of a test playlist: filtering by TestCategory or class name etc.

I am also aware that one can instruct TFS builds to only run certain categories or classes of test.

However, I find it quick and convenient to be able to check my unit test runs just by going into Test Explorer and clicking "run all". It's good practice to do this regularly and prior to check-in to ensure the build is likely to pass.

Is there a straightforward way I can configure my tests to ensure that "run all" just picks up the quick unit tests, and leaves the slower system and regression tests alone? Ideally, I'd like a method that can easily be applied to everyone else working on the code at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little incomprehensible. Since the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx#BKMK_Contents) explains very clear.`Run all` just mean run all tests. And there are also filters or other settings can achieve just run unit tests.

[image]

And also as your have mentioned, you can [run unit tests with your builds directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/test/continuous-testing/test-build). Why you need this function. If you just want to make sure the check-in will not cause build fail. You can use **[Gated Check-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd794776.aspx)** directly. This also applied to everyone else.